# How to get particular value from json string in Aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json, aura

I have below code where I am converting json.stringify and getting below output

```
let theData = JSON.stringify(helper.getData(component));
console.log('theData>>>' + theData);
```

output:

> {"userName":"sampleUser@test.com","profile":"Sales","Account":"Self","Contact":"Personal","Time":"IST"}

I need to get profile value in one var/let, but I am not able to understand how I can get the specific value.

I tried this but not working

```
var Profile = theData[0].get('profile'))
```

getting error. Please help

Comment: By the way, I made a guess on the answer. When you're asking a question, make sure you're specific about the error. "It doesn't work" or "getting error" doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you don't need to do JSON.stringify because its returning object.

so you can simple get profile value using below code

```
let theData =helper.getData(component);
console.log(theData.profile);
```

second way:

```
let theData = JSON.stringify(helper.getData(component));
let output = JSON.parse(theData);
console.log(output.profile);
```

Hope its help

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the value out of the String too easily, just leave it as an Object, which it is now.

```
let theData = helper.getData(component);
```

Based on your "output," it doesn't appear that this is an Array? Try:

```
let profileName = theData.profile;
```

If this is an Array, though, it would be simply:

```
let profileName = theData[0].profile;
```

Comment: thanks sfdcfox.This one is working for me       let theData = JSON.stringify(helper.getData(component));
let output = JSON.parse(theData);
console.log(output.profile);